Modelling a Poisson distribution with overdispersion, why does it lead to misleadingly small p-values?
For Poisson distribution, it is assumed that the variance is equal to the mean. However, in most situations the variance is larger than the mean when fitting Poisson data (Overdispersion).
Why does overdispersion lead to misleadingly small P-value.
How to accommodate this overdispersion when estimating the P-value?
